# Delete pods using kubectl containing a substring

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

When I run the command `kubectl get pods | grep "apisix"`, I get the following data

```
apisix-dev-78549978b7-pvh2v                           1/1     Running             6 (4m19s ago)   8m14s
apisix-dev-dashboard-646df79bf-mwkpc                  1/1     Running             6 (4m35s ago)   8m12s
apisix-dev-etcd-0                                     1/1     Running             0               8m12s
apisix-dev-etcd-1                                     1/1     Running             0               8m11s
apisix-dev-etcd-2                                     0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    4 (24s ago)     8m11s
apisix-dev-ingress-controller-58f7887759-28cm9        1/1     Running             0               8m11s
apisix-dev-ingress-controller-6cc65c7cb5-k6dx2        0/1     Init:0/1            0               8m9s
```

Is there any way to delete all the pods containing the word `apisix` instead of mentioning every pod name in kubectl delete command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run a simple command:

```
kubectl delete pod $(kubectl get pod | grep apisix | awk '{print $1}')
```

Answer (score 0):

A common way to select (and then, maybe delete) a set of Pods is via `selector` labels.

For example, assuming that a proper label `app` with value `apisix` exists:

```bash
# Find which Pods are selected (just to be sure)
kubectl get pod --selector=app=apisix

# Delete them (probably with --dry-run=client, if still unsure about what is selected)
kubectl delete pod --selector=app=apisix
```